# I am planning to design and develop price estimator(Simple Monthly Estimator) like the one AWS provides.Any suggestions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am thinking to add additional  USER and ADMIN functionality into it. Purpose is that it will give me more sophisticated and clear estimation of services cost so i could go on and make appropriate changes to environment to cut the unnecessary cost. I am planning to deploy it on AWS.

Comment: it's great only, at least you have a chance to learn while working on it. Just for your information, we are using 3rd party tool stax.io for the same, as the one from AWS is not so good.

Comment: Great.. Thank you!. How the tool helped you to estimate the cost more precisely?

Comment: It has a lot of feature, and breakdown the cost for all services, you can create trial account and take a look.